# TroubleShooting: Related Field got invalid lookup - icontain

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin-filters

```
class Job_type(models.model):
  created_by = UserForeignKey(auto_user_add=True, verbose_name="The user 
    that is automatically assigned", related_name="Job_type_created_by")
```

and in admin.py

```
@admin.register(Job_type)
class Job_type_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('id','job_type','is_deleted','is_active','created_by',
           'created_on','last_modified_by','last_modified_on')
list_display_links = ['id','job_type','created_by']
list_filter = ('job_type','created_by')
search_fields= ('id','job_type','created_by','created_on','last_modified_by','last_modified_on')
list_per_page = 20
```

please help me ,i want created by in search field but it is throwing error as Related Field got invalid lookup - icontain

Comment: It's `icontains`, not `icountain`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry my bad, thanks for the correction'

Comment: Can you please share your views.py for me to have a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to:

- the ForeignKey to User (implemented by UserForeignKey), field 'created_by'
- presence of 'created_by' in search_fields list

a way to solve this is to specify on which fields of User ('created_by') to enable the search, i.e. in the search_fields list try to replace 'created_by' with 'created_by__username'.